# head (title) doesn't update automatically in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The idea is to update title in head dynamically after each iteration, for example 
"documents signing 1/6" 
"documents signing 2/6"
...

and currently jQuery function is

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(this).attr("title", eval("constLang." + "TASK_SIGN") + " " + current_task + "/" + total_tasks);
        });
```

It works fine in Mozilla and Google chrome, bot doesn't appear in IE11

Comment: try `document.title` instead. eg: `document.title = eval("constLang." + "TASK_SIGN") + " " + current_task + "/" + total_tasks;`

Answer (score 0):

Simply get `title` by tag name:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('title').text(eval("constLang." + "TASK_SIGN") + " " + current_task + "/" + total_tasks);
});
```